# Changing text if a form has an error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I currently have a summary message at the top of my form, inviting my user to login. If the form does not validate on submit, I wish for this to then be replaced with the relevant error.

The only way I can think of is by hiding the initial text (perhaps in a `@Html.Label`) and then showing a `@Html.ValidationSummary`. However, I feel there is most likely a far more efficient way of doing this.

Can anybody help?

Comment: that was a quick response i deleted my original comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have an `@Html.Label` helper, and use the `ViewBag` object to pass data to it.  That way in your controller when you test for `ModelState.IsValid`, if that is false you can set the `ViewBag` property so that it passes to the label helper.

Make sense?  That's how I'd do it.

Answer (score 0):

turn on the validation summary

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
```

in your `post` ActionResult check the `ModelState`

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Foo( Bar _bar){

  if(ModelState.IsValid){
    //noral course of action
   return RedirectToAction("Foo"); //Redirect to the GET method
  }
   ModelState.AddModelError("", "|Your Message Here");
 return View(_bar);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @3nigma. I do however already have a validation summary - I was looking for the correct way to hide a message if this validation summary is shown.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no problem with the approach.
I generally use single div with jquery for the stuff like form validation etc.
I create a single div on page where any kind of message can be displayed for user guideance.

ex:
if I've display some kind of information to user, it will be displayed as following:

```
div id='divMessage'</div>

$('#divMessage').html('Please fill the following form.').removeClass().addClass('msg');
```

While in case of some error same div will be used to display the error message:

```
$('#divMessage').html('some error occurred.').removeClass().addClass('errmsg');
```

I hope till will be of any use.